# Why is my keyboard layout messed up when using X2Go and VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout, x2go

I connect to an Ubuntu server from my Mac via X2Go, using MATE.  I can type into almost any program with no problem.  If I open OnBoard, the layout looks correct, but when I click the button that has a `Q` on it, a `y` is typed, and all of the other keys are mismapped, too.  If I try to type into a VirtualBox machine with my physical keyboard, the keys are mismapped.

In the process of trying to figure this out, I did a `sudo apt-get remove ibus`.  I also tried various things in Keyboard Preferences.  Nothing is fixing it.  I'm using a normal US qwerty keyboard, and haven't intentionally used any abnormal keyboard layouts.

How can I get my physical keyboard to work as expected in all situations?

Comment: Since I haven't figured this out, I've been working around it.  I've been tunneling VirtualBox's remote display feature through ssh.  `ssh user@remotelinuxserver -T -L 12345:localhost:3389` then `rdesktop localhost:12345`.